# Use case diagram about System Hotel

Tags: uml, use-case

I would like to show use case diagram me.What is correct use case diagram me about system hotel?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPsZU.png

Note :
- outside of system boundary is comment, Not use case

sorry don't have reputation 10. Don't show image this.

Answer (score 0):

After a short review I would say that your use cases don't seem to be cut the right way. You are using `<<include>>` and `<<extend>>` in order to perform a functional analysis. This is not what use cases are all about. Each use case must show a piece of added value to its actor. I/E are a means of showing optionality for single UCs (means they can be added later in time or build a system with different level of value to the user). Showing a path of execution is something that goes completely into activity diagrams inside each use case.

As a take home message: If your UC diagrams start resembling a spider's web your design is likely broken.

Comment: design use case in visio, very hard :(
what is your improve use case me. I confused reference about use case diagram?

Comment: If you simply remove include/extent it will likely improve the quality.

Comment: why must remove include/extends? what is effect after remove include/extends?